# geting data from api jsonArray in android

Tags: android, arrays, json, parsing

I'm trying to get data from an api, but not getting the idea how. 
I'm working on a weather app, but weather condition is inside an array.

Look at this: [enter link description here](http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk)

When look at will see that the "weather" data is inside an array. all I want from this array is the "main" that inside it. So how it can be done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
JsonObject jsonData=new JsonObject(responseStr);

JsonObject main=jsonData.getJsonObject("main");

String temp=main.getString("temp");
.....
JsonArray weather=jsonData.getJsonArray("weather");
for(int i=0;i<weather.lenght.i++)
 {

  JsonObject weatherChild=(JsonObject)weather.get(i);
  String id=weatherChild.getString("id") ;
  .......
 }
```

Comment: yes this work with what inside the first array that in the json, but not with "weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"Sky is Clear","icon":"01d"}] because as you can see is an another array